# Argus TV Scheduler service doesn't start with Windows?

Tags: windows, kodi

In xbmc I always get an error message "TV client not connected". I find the error but it need to manually start the Argus TV scheduler service. Is there a way I can start it automatically with Windows?

Comment: setup a scheduled task to start it when the use logs into the account.

Comment: @Ramhound:Can you make an answer?

Comment: I would rather not.  Somebody else can if they choose to post the require screenshots to explain the process.

Comment: @Ramhound:That doesn't work you can't start a service with a task.

Comment: Yeah that's not correct I just looked this up earlier this week windows has hundreds of tasks that start a service

Comment: @Ramhound:Interesting. I think I solved my question but why would didn't you tell me before?

Comment: I did?  What do you mean exactly.  Are you really complaining about waiting?

Comment: @Ramhound:Your solution doesn't work and then you wrote earlier this week you made the same "mistake"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I look forward to you posting the solution that worked for you.  I am not going to elaborate for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound:I see now I understand. But I told you a task cannot run a service. Can you point me to a source? I mean task=scheduled task?